# Can I See the TEXT of an email invitation I sent for a Google Group?

Tags: google-groups

I've just set up a Google Group for a class I'm teaching this summer.  I sent my students email invitations and would like to keep a copy of that invitation's text for my records (as an example for the class itself - it's all so meta!!)

I've been searching for nearly an hour and cannot figure out how/if I can somehow retrieve that email invitation so that I can have a copy of the text.

- I can definitely see the outstanding invitations to my students, so apparently the email did send.
- If I try to re-invite someone, I do not get the same text in the little window that pops up for re-inviting.

Short of having a student forward the invite email BACK to me, is there any way I can access that (sent) email from within Google itself?  (it's not in my Gmail sent folder).

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is any way you can access the invitation email directly from within Google Groups.

The surefire way to get the text is to invite yourself to the group as well.  To avoid Google Groups complaining that you're already a member of the group, use a different email address.  This is easy to do if you use Gmail.  For example, if your address is `Amy@gmail.com`, you can invite `Amy+invite@gmail.com`.